# Can't run OpenCV Emgu.CV

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

Using the PM I installed Emgu.CV to my solution and wrote this very simple code:

```
    using (var img = new Image<Bgr, byte>("img4.png"))
    {
        using (var provider = new Tesseract("", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractCubeCombined))
        {
            provider.Recognize(img);

            var chars = provider.GetCharacters();

            var text = provider.GetText().TrimEnd();
        }
    }
```

For some strange reason, when I run the app, I get the exceptions:
1) The console displays the following:
error opening data file ./tessdata/eng.traineddata please make sure the tessdata_prefix environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory
Failed loading language "eng"
Tesseract couldn't load any languages

2) And the exception error in the code:
{"Unable to create ocr model using Path 'c:\users\jdoe\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\OpenCV_ImgToText\OpenCV_ImgToText\bin\Debug' and language 'eng'."}

Well, first of all I am not sure if I had to install anything before running this code.
I donwloaded the package from emgu.com, unzipped it but there is only the source code, so nothing to install
I also changed the folder permission to OpenCV_ImgToText, so now it can write the files into it. But the erorr still pops up.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have used OpenCV once. Following documentation helped me to create simple application with WCF.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation